# Discord.py how to check if input has a decimal

Tags: python, discord.py

i made this command it will purge the amount of messages that you said ie >purge 10 it will delete 10 messages i don't know how to check if the input was a decimal can you help 
Code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount=300):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.manage_messages:
        channel = ctx.message.channel
        messages = []
        async for message in client.logs_from(channel, limit=int(amount) + 1):
            messages.append(message)
        await client.delete_messages(messages)
        await client.say('Purged {} message(s)!'.format(len(messages)-1)) 
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = ':x: Insufficient Permissions',
            description = 'You need to have the Manage Messages premission to execute this command.',
            colour = 0xff0000
        )
        await client.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include more detail about the problem you are having, and what you have tried so far to fix it.  See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You can use type annotations to supply a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) (note that this is the [discord.py-rewrite](/questions/tagged/discord.py-rewrite) documentation, but this also works in the async branch) to your coroutine.  You can then specify another error handler that can implement your logic for dealing with bad input.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount: int=300):
    ...

@purge.error
async def purge_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Cannot convert input to integer")
```

You may also want to look at [`Client.purge_from`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest//api.html#discord.Client.purge_from).  I didn't read all of your coroutine, but it looks like you're reinventing the wheel a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the default value for the `amount` and catch the ValueError that is thrown when the user writes something wrong

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount):
  try:
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.manage_messages:
        channel = ctx.message.channel
        messages = []
        async for message in client.logs_from(channel, limit=int(amount) + 1):
            messages.append(message)
        try:
          await client.delete_messages(messages)
          await client.say('Purged {} message(s)!'.format(len(messages)-1))
        except Exception as inst:
          await client.say("One or more messages older than 14 days\n{}".format(inst))
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = ':x: Insufficient Permissions',
            description = 'You need to have the Manage Messages premission to execute this command.',
            colour = 0xff0000
        )
        await client.say(embed=embed)
  except ValueError as va:
    await client.say(va)
```

I've also added the try/except for when at least one of the messages is 14 days old and thus cannot be deleted